# How to install SQL Server Express 2005 with Full text search

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I am in need to Install SQL server 2005 Express edition with Full Text Search capability. I don't know what to download and the order of installing the Database management system. Could someone provide me link to download the version with Full Text Search [as default 38Mb setup file does not have this feature].
Also step by step instruction to enable Full Text Search during the installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full Text Search features are available in

[**Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition with Advanced Services**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4c6ba9fd-319a-4887-bc75-3b02b5e48a40&displaylang=en)
[**Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express with Advanced Services**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=B5D1B8C3-FDA5-4508-B0D0-1311D670E336&displaylang=en)

Installation and configuration are pretty simple, hope you have already installed express edition.

Give it a try!

UPDATE: 2011 - MARCH - 08

You will not be able manage Full Text Catalogs via SSMS.

> [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx)
>
> - You cannot update the full-text catalog by using SSMSE. You can use sqlcmd utility or Windows Scheduler to update the full-text catalog.

Comment: Great thanks for the link appreciate it, Installation went breeze

Comment: I am re-opening my question , Great that Full text service installs with the Installer file you specified but The management studio does not provide any of features to manage the Full Text catalogs. How do i get the management studio and not express editions

Comment: @Deeptechtons - Please update your question or create a new question to ask this particular issue; meanwhile I'll check the issue with  SSMS

Comment: @Sandy please do update on status and if you want me to[really,really,really] want me to open new question i would. But the basis and category falls into same question.

Comment: @Deeptechton - thats fine. I'v updated my answer. Feel free to unmark, if this answer doesn't help you.

Comment: Votes Up! sheesh doesnot allow me. But i think SQL Server Management Studio allows you to do that. Which btw comes packaged only along with Server 2005 Enterprise editions. Thanks helped me lot

Comment: @Deeptechtons - I've rejected your edit, because your above comment is fine.

Comment: @Deeptechtons - may be you can post your solution with SSMS 2005 Enterprise Edition as new answer to your own question.

Comment: i suppose so. but it would be come under different question